# Are Exchange ActiveSync .xsd schemas available outside of documentation?

Tags: exchange, activesync, xml

I'm working on an ActiveSync email client application (on Android, not that it matters). I would like to be able to write unit tests that validate the client's WBXML requests against Microsoft's published EAS schemas. Those schemas are available in Microsoft's documentation [(example)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn292972%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), but I'm hoping to avoid the need to copy and paste a bunch of XML from the documentation; more importantly, I'd like to have the versions of those schemas that go with earlier releases of Exchange, not just the latest.

The question: Are Microsoft's .xsd schemas available as discrete files anywhere? Are they shipped with Exchange itself, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be on your DVD/ISO.  EX 2010 location example:

```
x:\Setup\ServerRoles\ClientAccess\sync\xsd\v2.0  

 Directory of x:\Setup\ServerRoles\ClientAccess\sync\xsd\v2.0

09/25/2009  01:14 PM    <DIR>          .
09/25/2009  01:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             1,043 foldercreate-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM               751 folderdelete-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM               550 foldersync-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             1,189 folderupdate-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             1,166 getitemestimate-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             1,299 meetingresponse-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             1,261 moveitems-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             1,242 provision-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             2,003 search-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             8,358 sync-calendar-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM             7,119 sync-contacts-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM               261 sync-email-request.xsd
07/21/2009  08:27 PM            16,028 sync-request.xsd
```

Comment: Whether the question is off-topic or not, the answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks!